# VS 2015 referenced DLLs updated in bin dir of web app, even though no build triggered

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This is driving us nuts:

- Create an new solution in VS 2015.
- Add a class project called "Dependency"
- Add an empty web application called "Consuming"
- In "Dependency", add a nuget reference to Castle.Core, version 2.5.2
- In "Consuming", add a nuget reference to Castle.Core, version 3.3.3
  (you can use pacakges.config or project.json - makes no difference)
- Add a project reference from "Consuming" to "Dependency"

Now, build your entire sln and investigate the version of Castle.Core in the bin dir of "Consuming" - sure enough it is 3.3.3 as expected.

However, now do a *project build only* of "Dependency".  Magically, the Castle.Core DLL that is in the bin dir of "Consuming" is *updated to 2.5.2* - even though building "Dependency" should not trigger a build of "Consuming"

Now repeat the same process, but make "Consuming" be a console app - it does not happen!

What the hell is going on here?

(I'm pretty sure it's not nuget related: I think it will occur with regular assembly references)

**Update**
@Schwarzie2478 ask me to try the same sequence using MSBuild on the command line.  As I expected, the observed behaviour above does not happen, so this is a VS issue only:

- Starting with clean bin folders, MSBuild the sln:

```
PS v5 (0.0140067) D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest> msbuild /t:Build .\DependencyTest.sln
....
Project "D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\DependencyTest.sln" (1) is building "D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\WebApp\WebApp.csproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
....
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\packages\Castle.Core.3.3.3\lib\net45\Castle.Core.dll" to "bin\Castle.Core.dll".
    ...
```

At this point the version of the DLL in WebApp\bin\debug is 3.3.3

Now, build the dependency project on it's own - no build of "Consuming" is triggered:

```
PS v5 (2.8423647) D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest> msbuild /t:build .\Dependency\Dependency.csproj
...
Project "D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\Dependency\Dependency.csproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
...
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Dependency -> D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\Dependency\bin\Debug\Dependency.dll
Done Building Project "D:\Temp\DependencyTest\DependencyTest\Dependency\Dependency.csproj" (build target(s)).
```

As expected, no copy occurs into the "Consuming" bin dir of the WebApp.

In case anyone thinks this is just an interesting diversion, in an SLN that has many library projects with matching unit test projects this causes problems for test runners like R# which will do incremental builds of dependencies of the unit test projects.  This nasty side-effect causes all WebApplications in the sln to get their bin folders updated - even when they are not referenced by the unit test or library projects.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why keep two difference references?

Comment: Well, not a stupid question, but regardless it's still surprising behaviour...  The "Dependency" is a common project maintained by other teams and used in many solutions.  "Consuming" will declare a binding redirect which will keep castle.core code in Dependency.dll happy.

Comment: Change the msbuild verbosity to Detailed and it gets very chatty about this.  It is going to have to choose a victim project that is going to get the wrong version of the DLL.  It only has a shot at it when it knows about *all* the projects your solution uses of course.  None whatsoever when you build only a single project, as you found out.  The build trace should also show you why the console project is "special".  The distinction between a primary reference and an indirect reference matters, first one wins.

Comment: I think you misunderstand: I am building a single project inside VS while that sln is open.  That project (Dependency) has no reference to the other project (Consuming) in the sln, and indeed, Consuming is NOT actually built, yet the DLL *is* replaced in it's bin folder.

Comment: Have you built from the commandline yet?  We noticed different behavior in Project Resolving between using Visual Studio itself (devenv.exe) from the commandline and building with msbuild.  What happens when you build the solution ( with consuming disabled for the current configuration) with msbuild for instance?